# What is the difference between Wikipedia and New World Encyclopedia?

Tags: wikipedia

What is the difference between [Wikipedia](http://www.wikipedia.org/) and [New World Encyclopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/)?

And what is the point of having another version of Wikipedia-like site?

---

Related:

- [What exactly is the New World Encyclopedia?](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101228183037AAgrpBl) at Yahoo

Comment: You can get some insight in https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/New_World_Encyclopedia.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Yahoo question you linked to has the immediate answer:

> New World Encyclopedia is a wiki-based encyclopedia which contains carefully selected articles that are rewritten and supervised by a team of editors with academic and literary qualifications. New World Encyclopedia has the same ease of use as Wikipedia, but differs based on an editorial policy that includes a more rigorous article selection process, editorial review process, and its wholesome values orientation.
>   (From http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Info:Project_Vision)

It is included under the [List of Unification Church affiliated organizations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unification_Church_affiliated_organizations) page on Wikipedia with the note:

> an Internet encyclopedia that, in part, selects and rewrites certain Wikipedia articles through a focus on Unification values

In terms of differences, the two important points would be:

- Wikipedia is open to editing by anyone, where the New World Encyclopedia is edited by a select group
- Wikipedia articles are written according to a [set of criteria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:About#Wikipedia_content_criteria) including verifiability and a [Neutral Point of View](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Neutral_point_of_view), where the New Wold Encylopedia uses a different [set of values](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Help:Writers_Manual#Addressing_values_in_articles) and a "[Unification Point of View](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Help:Writers_Manual#Unification_point_of_view_.28UPOV.29)".

Answer (score 3):

It's a wiki with generally somewhat okay information on non-scientific and philosophical matters, but with a strong pro-creationist, anti-atheist (to the point of bigotry) stance.